# Get Array data (serialized data?) and display, this code functions good, but why, and is it proper?

Tags: php, wordpress

I first posted this question in the wordpress.stackexchange site and they rejected/closed the question saying its not specific enough to wordpress and they recommend I post it here. Hope its good to post here!

I wrote this code to use when 'getting' database data that was saved in WordPress custom wp options.

I really don't understand what the code is doing completely so if you can explain it please. And also tell me if it's even **proper code** or if I should use different code.

The reason I first started using this code is when I tried to get the data from the database data is in an **Array** and trying to display the data with just the first **$name** gives a php/array error, so for example

**echo $name** gives error;

so if I use the code and display for example

**echo $thename**, this functions good without error.

I also use the normal get_option code to get the data like this:

**$name = get_option('custom_name');**

The main question is about the code below:

```
if (!empty($name)) :
 foreach($name as $thename)
 {
  $name = $thename;
 }
endif;
```

The data is a normal php/mysql data array and the data in the array is simple words, titles, etc.

I don't know why it works or if it's proper to use for getting data with get_option.

Please write me any comments or improvements so I learn and my code is more proper.

Edit: I think the data is what is called **serialized** data.

Comment: `$name`is an array, so you can't echo it directly, you should use `print_r($name)`or`var_dump($name)`. The `foreach` code you are using can be replaced by `$name = last($name)`, that means you get the last element in the array

Comment: Thanks. Sounds good, but that also gives an error, it says last() is undefined function.

Comment: I also tried something different. I tried: return array($name); Displays no error but does not display anything.

Comment: And also tried print_r alone. And is shows this error. Notice: Array to string conversion in...

Comment: I think I solved this. I removed the foreach completely. Then I wrote the option name in the get_option line. Then I wrote the option title (?) or the first word in the data which I guess might be called the option title. Then this prints or echos the correct data from that section in the data. Without foreach!

Comment: So this is what the display line is like now:  echo $name['datatitle'];

Comment: Arrays have indexes. By accessing an index, you get the value of that index. `$name` is the array, and your solution was made by specifically stating which value you wanted from the array according to the appropriate index. So, `$name['the_index']`.

Comment: If anyone knows, I still want to understand why did my mistake of using foreach function without the index name with no error, equal to using the correct $name['the_index']?